# Can someone help me figure out what the noble gas configurations for zirconium and holmium are?

Tags: electrons, electronic-configuration, elements, noble-gases

**I am currently working on noble gas configurations in chemistry and I am having a hard time understanding why I got two questions wrong on a practice.**

**The instructions for the practice are here:**

Write out the noble gas configuration for the element. Enter your answer with all values without any spaces, hyper scripts or subscripts

Example: Sulfur S - $\ce{[Ne] 3s^2 3p^4}$   -->  [Ne]3s23p4

**My questions are:**

1. Write the noble gas configuration for Zr:
2. Write the noble gas configuration for Ho:

**My answers were:**

1. $\ce{[Kr] 5s^2 4p^6 4d^2}$ -->  [Kr]5s24p64d2
2. $\ce{[Xe] 6s^2 5p^6 4f^{11}}$  -->  [Xe]6s25p64f11

**I am still getting the answers wrong. Where did I go wrong in my configurations?**

Comment: Check the prefixes for s and p orbitals.

Comment: What does that mean? Can you show me what that looks like? Are my letters not in the correct order?

Comment: 4p is part of [Kr], so does 5p of [Xe]. Check the periodic table.

Comment: I'm still not understanding.

Comment: As a steering wheel is a part of a car, we do not say there is a car and a steering wheel in the garage, do we ?

Comment: I don't know wether Zr and Ho have a "noble gas configuration" (sounds ridiculous to me), but the answers expected are the same as for the electron configurations of, say, iodide and astatide ions?

Comment: Are you saying the electron configurations of iodide and astatide are the same electron configurations for both Zr and Ho?

Comment: No, I'm saying your teacher is stupid. This question makes no sense. Neither Zr nor Ho are noble gases. Does he mean ground state configuration? Or should you strip off or fill in electrons until you get a noble gas configuration? $\ce{Zr^{4+}}$ is OK, with Ho that doesn't work in reality. This question is unchemical. The example points to the former, i.e. ground state. But what have you been taught if you thought this was called a noble gas electron configuration?

Comment: I add to Karl comment otherwise OP might get even more confused. It is not a real chemistry mistake but rather language, or viceversa. Or both. What you are actually asked to do is to write down the electronic configuration of an element and render it in a more compact, short form by using the preceding noble gas one instead of carrying a long string of character. Nothing about chemistry in a way. But at beginning we all have to do it. Hope this helps. For the actual question see other comments or answers I am not going to check this exercise.

Comment: "noble gas configuration for zirconium" is a terrible slang to be taken "configuration of zirconium written using the previous nearest noble gas and adding the remaining electrons".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Zirconium is $\ce{[Kr] 4d^2 5s^2}$. Holmium is $\ce{[Xe] 4f^{11} 6s^2}$. But they don't have the configuration of a rare gas.

Comment: Is this the answer?

Comment: @AudreyW.- No that is not correct. Zirconium is $\ce{[Kr] 4d^2 5s^2}$

Comment: @ MaxW. Thank you. My mistake was ridiculous.